# Create unique arrays based on dataset with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello need help creating separate arrays based on data value.

I have

`<input hidden data-size="120x40" data-color="Brown" data-tab="Gardenbox Professional">`

`<input hidden data-size="160x40" data-color="Brown" data-tab="Gardenbox ECO">`

`<input hidden data-size="120x40" data-color="Red" data-tab="Gardenbox Professional">`

`<input hidden data-size="160x40" data-color="Red" data-tab="Gardenbox ECO">`

and there's like 50 of those.

I need to create unique arrays/object based on **data-tab**.

Is there a way for that?

Comment: Could you indicate the data structure you would like to achieve? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This gives you an object with multiple arrays for each unique **data-tab** value.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');    
var object = {};
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  if(!object.hasOwnProperty(inputs[i].getAttribute('data-tab'))){
    object[inputs[i].getAttribute('data-tab')] = [];
  }
   var subObject = {};
   subObject["size"] = inputs[i].getAttribute('data-size');
   subObject["color"] = inputs[i].getAttribute('data-color');
   subObject["tab"] = inputs[i].getAttribute('data-tab');
   object[inputs[i].getAttribute('data-tab')].push(subObject); 
  
}
console.log(object);
```

```html
<input hidden data-key="item1" data-size="120x40" data-color="Brown" data-tab="Gardenbox Professional">

<input hidden data-key="item2" data-size="160x40" data-color="Brown" data-tab="Gardenbox ECO">

<input hidden data-key="item3" data-size="120x40" data-color="Red" data-tab="Gardenbox Professional">

<input hidden data-key="item4" data-size="160x40" data-color="Red" data-tab="Gardenbox ECO">
```